# Failed to launch debug adapter 'coreclr'

Tags: docker, visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging

I'm trying to attach a remote docker container from Visual Studio 2022, and I'm getting this error. The error says it is permission related but I can run that command via the terminal.

I guess Visual Studio tries to run that command with a different user.

- Visual Studio runs on Windows 10
- Docker container runs on Ubuntu (Azure VM)

I can be able to see running images on Linux from Visual Studio which means that I correctly set the configuration.

[image]

The error is;

```
Failed to launch debug adapter 'coreclr'.
Unable to find debugger script at '/home/devadmin/.vs-debugger'.


Initialization log:
Determining user folder on remote system...
Checking for existing installation of debugging tools...
Downloading debugger launcher...
Creating debugger installation folder: /home/devadmin/.vs-debugger
Failed: "Command 'mkdir -p '/home/devadmin/.vs-debugger'' failed with code '1'. "
Unable to find debugger script at '/home/devadmin/.vs-debugger'.
Failed: Unable to find debugger script at '/home/devadmin/.vs-debugger'.
The program '[1] CoreServer' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```

I tried to attach remote Docker (Linux) process from Windows machine, and I got an error.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the container in Visual Studio
2. Right-click on the container and select “Open terminal”
3. Inside the terminal that has opened, run the following commands in
   this order:
4. apt-get update
5. apt-get install procps -y
6. apt-get install wget -y
7. mkdir /root/.vs-debugger
8. curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh -o
   ‘/root/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh’
9. bash /root/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh -v latest -l /vsdbg
10. Change the build mode in VS to Debug
11. Attach the debugger